# In a table cell, center a canvas element but not its siblings

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have this HTML code:

```
<tbody>
     <tr>
         <td>
             <canvas class="myid_templates_editor_canvas"></canvas>
             <div>A lot of codes here</div>
             <div>A lot of codes here</div>
         </td>
     </tr>
<tbody>
```

I want to center only the `canvas` and not other child elements of `td`. So I tried the css below:

```
td {
    text-align:center;
}
```

But the code affects the other elements `<div>`. I tried the code:

```
td > canvas {
    text-align:center;
}
```

The code above doesn't center my canvas element? What shall I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a fixed `width` and then `margin: auto` , also `display: block`. `text-align: center` will make center all contents.

```
canvas.myid_templates_editor_canvas {
    width: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4dcq8rx/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
td {
 text-align:center; 
}

td div {
 text-align:left;
}

table {
 width: 100%;
}
```